# Add nav dots to fancybox

Tags: navigation, fancybox, slideshow, image-gallery

I want to add basic navigation dots to my fancybox slideshow.

Example here: 
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

But I cant get this to work. Not sure if I am editing the JS in the right place.

It's driving me crazy - any help would be great.

Thanks

**Here is my html:**

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery1" href="images/index/Dwayne5.jpg" >     
                        <!--slideshow image 1-->

<img src="images/index/artfuldogerthumbnail.jpg" alt="main icon" />
                          <!--This is the little image on page-->
</a>




<a class="fancybox-thumb"rel="gallery1"href="images/index/artfuldogerthumbnail.jpg" title="colour dodger"> 
                            <!--slideshow image 2-->

 </a>

 <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery1"href="images/index/sheree.png" title="">
 </a>
                            <!--slideshow image 2-->
```

****Here is my JS****

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
            prevEffect  : 'none',
            nextEffect  : 'none',
            helpers : {
                title   : {
                    type: 'outside'
                },
                thumbs  : {
                    width   : 50,
                    height  : 50
                }
            }
        });
    });

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });

        $.fancybox.helpers.thumbs.onUpdate = function() {};
    <!-- Above line stops thumbnails moving) -->


</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/zjvs31ht/1/ ?

Comment: Yes! Though I ended up doing it some other way. I can't even remember, I took the thumbnails themselves, removed the image/blocked the 'find url' and styled the containers... I think that makes sense.

You can see here
Shereewalker.com